# Saving image to mysql database as BLOB from android device

Tags: android

I want to upload an image to `mysql` database as `BLOB` data type. Would i have to convert image to BLOB data type from android and then upload it to the `mysql` database? i am using php as server side script.

-Thanks

Comment: No. Just upload the image as is to the php script. Then the script can put it in the db as BLOB.